# Why is my RethinkDB update query "terminated by an unknown cause"

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

When I run this query:

```
r.db('geodata').table('os50kgazetteer')
  .getAll(false, { index: 'has_geolocation' })
  .update({'geolocation': r.point(r.row('Coordinates')(0),r.row('Coordinates')(1))}
)
```

after several minutes of activity (a lot of reads followed by some writes) I receive the following error message:

```
e: Query terminated by an unknown cause in:
r.db("geodata").table("os50kgazetteer").getAll(false, {"index": "has_geolocation"}).update({"geolocation": r.point(r.row("Coordinates")(0), r.row("Coordinates")(1))})
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Some of the documents get updated, but only a few thousand out of the 250K+ in the table.

I would have thought it should always be possible to know the cause of an error - that seems sloppy to me and makes the error message essentially worthless.

Documents in the table look like this (this is one that has been correctly updated, as it has the `geolocation` field):

[image]

Is there anything obviously wrong with this query?

NOTE: I'm running the preview release of the Windows version of RethinkDB (2.2.4-windows-alpha-4) so it could be a bug...

Comment: That sounds like it's probably a bug in the windows port; you should never get "Query terminated by an unknown cause." in the course of normal operation.  I would open an issue on GitHub about it.

Comment: Actually, I tried the C# driver and when I run its unit tests, that kills the database stone dead (the process terminates). Looks like the Windows port isn't too stable at the moment.